# TextureAttribute.createDiffuse leaks memory?

Tags: memory-leaks, libgdx

I am setting a texture on a material with this code. Under Memory tab in Android studio, I noticed that memory increases each time when this code runs. Looks like memory leak or bad memory management to me. How should I set texture repeatedly at runtime to a material so that memory gets managed properly.

Code:

```
Timer.schedule(new Timer.Task() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    materials.get(5).set(TextureAttribute.createDiffuse(new Texture("400px/"+mat5+".png")));

                }
            }, delay2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is every time the `Timer` executed the `Task`, you're creating a new [Texture](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Texture.html). `Textures` are `Disposable` and as such, need to be `disposed` when not used anymore. In your above code, you aren't keeping a reference to the created `Textures` so you lose the ability to `dispose` of them. This creates memory leaks.

One solution to this, is to use an [AssetManager](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets) instead of managing your assets yourself. This class aims to relieve you of the effort of managing your assets' memory consumption.

Another solution is to keep references to the created `Texutres` and makeing sure they are properly `disposed` when not needed.

Personally, I'd go with the first solution. It might be intimidating at first, but once `AssetsManager` is mastered, it really does a good job when it comes to, well, managing your assets.